# Adding default route permanently

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I need to add a default route permanently in rocky Linux. The VM that I am using does not have a physical NIC and it cannot have one (for security reasons). That means when you run `nmtui` you do not see any network interface but the machine is part of a private network with a cidr like `10.10.0.0/16`. For certain reasons (setting up private Kubernetes) I have to specify the default route otherwise I will run into some problems. I can do this by running `ip route add default via 10.10.0.1` and that works perfectly.

However, when I restart the machine that route is lost and I have to add it again. I have tried adding it to the `motd` file and I also tried creating a bash file in `init.d` folder. When the system starts up the console prints `ip route add default via 10.10.0.1` twice meaning that both methods work but the route is not added and I still have to do this manually. When I run the command again it does not complain about the route being set again and then it works.

In the `network-script` folder there is also no file that I can modify!

How can I make this simple command execute anytime the system starts up or how can I make it permanent?

Comment: `network interface` doesn't have to be a `physical NIC`. Besides, from the VM's point of view, a virtual/emulated NIC is a physical NIC. Find out what manages/configures the interface on your VM (i.e. what configures the 10.0.0.x IP on it) and set the default gateway to use there. (Perhaps it is got the IP from a DHCP server running on the host side and the server does not advertise a default gateway; in that case you'll need to decide what to do. For example, change the configuration of the DHCP server, or configure static IP on the VM, or some automation that runs the `ip` command.)